# Create Sequence Connector

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect, connector

I would like to create programmatically a self-connector, using C#.

This is how I do it in case of an Association connector:

```
//Create new Association connector 
object connectorObject = selElement.Connectors.AddNew("NewConnector", "Association");
EA.Connector connector = connectorObject as EA.Connector;
if (connector != null)
  {
    //self-connector
    connector.SupplierID = selElement.ElementID;
    connector.ClientID = selElement.ElementID;
    connector.Update();
    selElement.Update();
    selDiagram.Update();  
  }
```

But when I try to create a sequence connector I get the following error:

```
object connectorObject = selElement.Connectors.AddNew("NewConnector", "Sequence");
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence is only allowed for lifelines in a sequence diagram. Elsewhere it will not show up.

I was able to create such a connector for elements but they will not show in class diagrams.

Also I did not see the error you got. It might come from an MDG with own validation rules.

Edit: If you create a sequence manually from the toolbox (Other/UML/Interaction/Message) the connector also appears on class diagrams - but very strange xD

EDIT (from Geert): Deselecting the Tools -> Options -> Links -> Strict Connector Syntax suppresses the error message box.

Comment: I think the error is due to the "strict connector syntax" checkbox in the Options

Comment: I have that option set but the message does not show. I remember having seen it once but here it did not show up. The connector is created though invalid. Strange.

Comment: Check the release notes for v12.1208 -> "Sequence messages can now be created from automation with strict connector syntax enabled"

Comment: I used 1206 - will try with 1208 and see if the message will pop up.

Comment: Nope. My guess is that the message only pops up when you use it inside an add-in. I tested it from a stand-alone program. Edit: nope too. Puzzled